# phantomjs page.open() doesn't seem to exist

Tags: java, phantomjs

I am trying to fetch page content with phantomjs. In many examples on the official site (eg.: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/imagebin.js) the function page.open() is used.
In my script though it does not seem to work. I used reflection to look at all defined methods of the page object:

```
  for ( var prop in page) {
      if (typeof page[prop] == 'function') {
          log("method in page: " + prop);
      }
  }
```

and the open() method did not show up. (close(), render(), etc... did show up)
also when I am trying to execute a script:

```
// include plugins
var system = require('system');
var fileSystem = require('fs');
var page = require('webpage').create();

// global errorhandler
phantom.onError = function(msg, trace) {
  console.log("ERROR!!!!! \n" + msg);
  phantom.exit(1);
};

// read json input and remove single outer quotes if set
var jsonin = system.args[1];
if (jsonin.charAt(0) == "'") {
  jsonin = jsonin.substr(1, jsonin.length - 2);
}
// make object of json
var data = eval('(' + jsonin + ')');
// optional url
var url = system.args[2];
// transfer file
var dest = system.args[3];

console.log("systemargs[1]: data -> " + data);
console.log("systemargs[2]: url -> " + url);
console.log("systemargs[3]: dest -> " + dest);

openRoot();

/*
 * open site
 */
function openRoot() {    
  page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log('INNER ' + msg);
  };

  page.open(url, function(status) {
    if (status === "success") {
      if (loadCount == 0) { // only initial open
        console.log("opened successfully.");
        page.injectJs("./jquery-1.8.3.min.js");
      } else {
        console.log("page open error.");
        console.log('skip refresh ' + loadCount);
      }

    } else {
      console.log("error opening: " + status);
    }
  });
}
phantom.exit(0);
```

it does not execute the open function. The log does not show any messages inside the open() method.

Any advice on what I might do wrong would be greatly appreciated. If there is additional information required, please let me know.
Regards,
Alex

Edit:
The line

```
console.log(typeof (page.open));
```

outputs: `function` which is not what I expected, given the previous list of methods I wrote to the log, where `open` does not exist. Hmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours of senseless searching I found the mistake. Stupid me. At the end of the script I call `phantom.exit()` where I should not.

The working code includes an Interval which checks on an object, in my case `content` and a member of that `content.isFinished`. If I set this to true, then `phantom.exit()` gets called.
My bad, absolutely my fault.
Working code:

```
var url = system.args[2];
// transfer file
var dest = system.args[3];

content = new Object();
content.isFinished = false;

console.log("systemargs[1]: data -> " + data);
console.log("systemargs[2]: url -> " + url);
console.log("systemargs[3]: dest -> " + dest);

openRoot();

/*
 * open site
 */
function openRoot() {    
  page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    console.log('INNER ' + msg);
  };

  page.open(url, function(status) {
    if (status === "success") {
      if (loadCount == 0) { // only initial open
        console.log("opened successfully.");
        page.injectJs("./jquery-1.8.3.min.js");

        // do stuff
        content.isFinished = true;
      } else {
        console.log("page open error.");
        console.log('skip refresh ' + loadCount);
        content.isFinished = true
      }

    } else {
      console.log("error opening: " + status);
    }
  });
}

/*
 * wait for completion
 */
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  if (content.isFinished) {
    page.close();

    f = fileSystem.open(dest, "w");
    f.writeLine(out);
    f.close();

    // exit phantom
    phantom.exit();
  } else {
    console.log('not finished - wait.');
  }
}, 5000);
```

Regards,
Alex